Identify true story film about two criminals, big shoot out at the end
I'm trying to remember an american film, or find out about the true events on which it was based, that I saw on UK TV in the late 80s or early 90s.  I'm sure it was based on true events about two criminals - both white males and set in modern America.  I don't remember anything about the film except that it culminates in a big shoot out on a freeway.  The criminals are essentially cornered and massively outnumbered by police but they refuse to give up - they keep shooting and getting shot, but they keep fighting.  I think at one point the car stops but they still keep fighting, using the doors as shields and even pushing the car as they still try to escape.  Eventually of course they are overwhelmed and succumb to their injuries and the film ends with captions and photos (maybe even video) of the real event that say something like:

This was the biggest shootout in American police history

or

More police died in this shootout than any other

or 

The criminals took more bullet wounds before dying than any other

I think the film followed the criminals rather than the police hunt and thus may have made them seem quite heroic for putting up strong fight at the end.  I think they were a bit redneck-ish or blue collar types and their car was pale, possibly blue or white.

I think you are looking for this TV movie:
"In the Line of Duty: The F.B.I. Murders" (1988)
From Wikipedia:

This film is about a real event that occurred April 11, 1986. Two
  former army buddies, Mike Platt (played by David Soul) and Bill Matix
  (Michael Gross), commit a series of murders and bank robberies in
  Miami, Florida; a group of F.B.I. agents led by Benjamin Grogan (Ronny
  Cox), is designated to carry out the investigation. The story
  concludes with one of the bloodiest clashes in FBI history, the 1986
  FBI Miami shootout.

It was made in 1988, it is based on a true event, two criminals who look red-neckish (see the poster below):

The complete movie can be watched here:



The movie starts with the following text card:

And at the end of the movie photos of the FBI agents involved are shown (like the one below):


Yes, this is definitely it.  I watched the last few minutes of the youtube link and it all looks very familiar - even though I got some details wrong.  Thanks.

Probably 44 Minutes: The North Hollywood Shoot-Out (2003)
Wikipedia

Homicide detective Frank McGregor (Michael Madsen) tracks a violent duo of bank robbers: Larry Eugene Phillips, Jr. and Emil Mătăsăreanu, who were named the High Incident Bandits by the LAPD.
On the morning of February 28, 1997, police officers get ready for work, while Phillips and Mătăsăreanu prepare to loot an armored bank truck. Meanwhile, SWAT officer Donnie Anderson (Ron Livingston) is mourning the death of his father, who was a policeman for over 31 years. He displays a lack of coordination with his unit during a raid on an apartment building, which almost causes one of his team members to be left alone with suspects, and is forced by his superior to take time off. Meanwhile, Phillips and Mătăsăreanu park outside the North Hollywood branch of Bank of America and wait for the armored truck to arrive. 
They are frustrated when the truck does not turn up and decide on robbing the bank instead. Donning black masks and homemade body armor, they enter the branch, firing at the roof with AK-47s. At the same time, an LAPD patrol car passes by and the officers observe the robbers entering the bank and call in a 211 for an armed robbery.
Phillips and Mătăsăreanu force the manager to open the vault and fill a duffel bag with all of the cash in the branch. While Mătăsăreanu has his back turned, the manager places a stack of notes rigged with a dye pack. With other officers arriving and setting up positions surrounding the bank, Phillips is shocked to see dozens of them and decides to walk outside, firing at them with his AK-47 and quickly being joined by Mătăsăreanu. The officers are heavily outgunned in the shootout. Anderson listens to the call on his radio, gathers his SWAT team, and races to the bank. After several minutes of firing and injuring both officers and civilians, Phillips and Mătăsăreanu decide to make a getaway. Mătăsăreanu drives their car while Phillips walks beside it and provides cover fire.
On Archwood Street, Phillips separates from Mătăsăreanu and starts firing randomly at the pursuing officers. While reloading, Phillips' AK-47 jams, and he is unable to clear it. He draws a pistol. Raising the finger, he continues firing at the officers. Then, he turns the pistol on himself, shooting himself under the chin while being simultaneously shot by McGregor. Meanwhile, Mătăsăreanu carjacks a pickup truck but is unable to start the engine since the driver disabled the fuel tanks before fleeing. The SWAT team arrives and corners Mătăsăreanu, who then takes cover behind his car, and a close-range gunfight ensues. The SWAT team eventually fires below the cars at Mătăsăreanu's legs; Mătăsăreanu is repeatedly hit in the feet and legs. Severely wounded, he drops his weapon and surrenders. It is later revealed that he dies of his gunshot wounds at the scene before paramedics can arrive.
The ending notes how the aftermath of the shootout proved to be a miracle, with no civilian or police deaths. It also notes how public opinion of the LAPD went up immensely due to their handling of the shootout. Actual footage is shown of LAPD officers receiving medals of valor and the public sending them thank-you notes and flowers in appreciation of their heroic efforts. McGregor closes by noting in an interview that "in 44 minutes of sheer terror, not one officer ran away. Everyone did their job, and I think that means something."


Based on a true story - Wikipedia

Due to the large number of injuries, rounds fired, weapons used, and overall length of the shootout, it is regarded as one of the longest and bloodiest events in American police history. Both men had fired approximately 1,100 rounds, while approximately 650 rounds were fired by police. Another estimate is that a total of nearly 2,000 rounds were fired.

